# When should I use {{attributes}} in twig opposed to hardcoding attributes?

Tags: templates, twig, drupal-8

I was reading up on template development in Drupal. ( https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates )

Drupal recommends creating an attributes object with `create_attribute()` and use the object that it creates to declare attributes to a html element. E.g.:

```
<div{{ create_attribute({'class': ['region', 'region--header']}) }}>
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

Where I would usually just use:

```
<div class='region region--header'>
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

I can imagine that this could be useful if you need to add attributes using some conditional logic. But I wouldn't want too much logic in a template.

I probably missed something essential here. Can someone clarify what the advantages of using `create_attribute()` are over hardcoding classes? When should I use the `create_atribute()` approach? What is a common scenario where the `create_attribute()` comes in handy?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no benefit of create_attribute() in your example, because attributes values are still hardcoded within create_attribute() function.

It is way more useful if attributes are hold in a variable that can be manipulated in (extended) templates with functions like addClass, removeClass, setAttribute,... For example we define attributes array (in twig or in processors) for given html element and you would simply render attributes with `<div {{ create_attribute(attributes_for_this_div) }}></div>`.

In Drupal core or in commonly used modules, I did not find single example of create_attribute() with hardcorded attributes.